# Does Ant offer a way to bypass dependency?

Tags: ant, build

The build.xml has a *test* and a *build* target. The *test* target obviously depends on the *build* target.

How can I run the test target only, **temporarily** skipping the compilation, without modifying the build.xml file ?

I'm asking because the compilation is too long, and kept up-to-date by a continuous integration server ; and I'm chasing after an issue with the unit tests.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you can't skip it without modifying the build file.

Here is what I do in my projects to solve this issue.
For every public target I will create a private target with "do-" in front of it.
The private target has no dependency, and the public target has the "do-" target as a dependency.

For example:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init, do-compile" description="Compiles all of the source code" />

<target name="do-compile">
        <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
            <src refid="src.path" />
            <include name="*.java" />
            <classpath refid="external.libraries.classpath" />
        </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: Sounds like we work in similar ways - it's nice to know I'm not alone on this front :)

Answer (score 32):

Use the `unless` attribute.

```
<target name="test" unless="dont.run.tests">
```

If you don't want "test" to run, just

> ant -Ddont.run.tests=true

It should be undefined if you want the tests to run. Ant just checks for whether it's defined at all. Also, there's an `if` attribute that does the converse.

Here's an [article](http://ideoplex.com/id/136/conditional-execution-in-ant) on the both.

Comment: This is the correct approach, should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Personally I've found the dependency stuff in Ant to get in the way more than helping. I usually set up two sets of targets - ones which actually *do stuff* (with no dependencies) and then targets which *just* have dependencies. That way you can easily run a single target, and you can also easily run the whole suite etc. This fits in with *practical* (rather than ideological) uses in my view.

Answer (score 2):

A well written build target will not need to rebuild anything if the code hasn't changed.  So the fact that the test target depends on it should be largely irrelevant.  If you run the build target twice in a row and it tries to rebuild something the second time, you might want to investigate why it is doing that.

The simple way to avoid executing the target is to set the "unless" attribute of the target to the name of some property.  If you then set this property on the command line when running Ant, it will bypass that target.

Comment: Agreed, but Ant is just used to bootstrap Makefile-based compilation of a large codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just "remove" the dependency temporarily?`If the code is built already all your files should be available, no? - oops, just saw that you cannot alter the file, hmm, why don´t you run the same job locally first?