# How do I prevent a dependency from executing in Ant?

Tags: ant

When debugging a build.xml file, or an Ant task, I often want to execute one task without executing its dependencies. Is there a way to do this from the command line?

For example, with this build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <target name="A" />
    <target name="B" depends="A" />
</project>
```

is there a command that will execute task B but not task A?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374673/does-ant-offer-a-way-to-bypass-dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make execution of any target conditional on a property using `if` or `unless`.

```
<project default="B">

    <target name="A" unless="no.a">
        <echo>in A</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="B" depends="A" >
        <echo>in B</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Output with no condition specified:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml

A:
     [echo] in A

B:
     [echo] in B

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Output with condition specified on command line:

```
$ ant -Dno.a=any
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml

A:

B:
     [echo] in B

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Notes:

- Ant console output will show that the target was "hit" even if entry was blocked by the condition.
- The `if` and `unless` conditions do not do boolean check. They just check whether the property is defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to restructure your Ant script to achieve this:

```
<target name="B">
    <if>
        <isset property="some.property"/>
        <then>
            <antcall target="A">
        </then>
    </if>
    <!-- execute task B here -->
</target>
```

If `some.property` is set, then it will first execute `A` followed by `B`.  Otherwise, it will skip task `A` and execute `B` by itself.